# Deriving Fick's first law

Tags: conservation-laws, diffusion

I have a problem understanding the derivation of Fick's first law. I have used the following link as a guide: http://web.mit.edu/biophysics/sbio/PDFs/L15_notes.pdf

I liked that way of deriving it, but my problem is that I don't understand what happened to the number 2 in the denominator from equation [x.2] in the link:

$J=-\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{2\tau}\frac{(C(x+\Delta x)-C(x))}{\Delta x}=-D\frac{dCx)}{dx}$

where $D$ is defined as: $D=\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{\tau}$.

Does anyone understand what happened to the number 2 in the denominator?

Comment: The factor 1/2 should be included in D. It's a typo. See the section on random walks, where D appears again.